# Match 6 digits between underscores

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a group of 6 digits between underscores. Here's what I currently have:

`^[^_]+_([^_]+)_[^_]+$`

I'm not sure how to specify that the group of numbers must be of length 6.

Example:

`4234_154356_423423` should match `154356` (it currently does, but it will also match any length of digits between _ and _)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
_(\d{6})_
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/LUjLFS/2/).
Additionally, as with any regex question, please provide the flavor used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fixed quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
_([0-9]{6})_
```

`[0-9]{6}` will only match 6 digits between 2 underscores.

Comment: My input string is `S1A_IW_SLC__1SSV_20161231T143332_20161231T143400_014625_017C68_A2A5` and I would like to match `014625` but it's not matching it with this. Does it have to do with types?

Comment: Just remove the anchors from regex or see the update

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
^[^_]+_(\d{6})_[^_]+$
```

`\d` - digits
`{6}` - length

Comment: My input string is `S1A_IW_SLC__1SSV_20161231T143332_20161231T143400_014625_017C68_A2A5` and I would like to match `014625` but it's not matching it with this. Does it have to do with types?

Comment: Then use `_(\d{6})_`